# How to read a file and store them in dictionary. without using zip

Tags: python, dictionary

I need to read the file that contains first line as a key and the second line as a value. I am able to open the file and read it but i am not able to assign it to the dictionary format.

```
def ticker(n):
infile = open(n)
content = infile.readlines()
c = {}
for lines in content:
    print (lines)
```

Below is my output, but i am not able to assign the first line to key and second line to value.

```
WHOLE FOODS MARKET
WFMI
WYNN RESORTS, LTD
WYNN
XILINX
XLNX
XM SATELLITE RADIO HOLDINGS
XMSR
YAHOO
YHO
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Use a dict generator:

```
{content[i]:content[i+1] for i in range(0, len(content)-1, 2)}
```

In your code like so:

```
def ticker(n):
    infile = open(n)
    content = infile.readlines()
    infile.close()  # Remember to close your file objects... (or use with block)
    return {content[i].strip():content[i+1].strip() for i in range(0, len(content)-1, 2)}
```

Or, as @ShadowRanger suggests using zip and slices:

```
def ticker(n):
    with open(n) as infile:
        content = infile.readlines()
        return dict(zip(content[::2], content[1::2]))
```

Comment: If you're going to slurp the whole file up front, you may as well just simplify using slices: `return dict(zip(content[::2], content[1::2]))`

Comment: @DavidZemens sorry i should have mentioned we are not allowed to use zip yet and also i am getting below new line character on the output.
    {'\n': '\n',
 'ACTIVISION INC  \t\n': 'ATVI\n',
 'ADOBE SYS INC\n': 'ADBE\n',
 'ALTERA CORP \t\n': 'ALTR\n',
 'AMAZON \t\n': 'AMZN\n',
 'AMERICAN POWER CONVER CORP \t\n': 'APCC\n'

Comment: Use the `strip()` method `{content[i].strip():content[i+1].strip() for i in range(0, len(content)-1, 2)}`

Answer (score 0):

You'd use `zip`, but not with `tee`, since that would pair all lines with their next line, not even lines with odd.  To pair even with odd, do:

```
def ticker(file_name):
   with open(file_name) as f:
      stripped = iter(map(str.rstrip, f))
      return dict(zip(*([stripped] * 2)))
```

This is just wrapping a `dict` constructor around an inlined version of the [`grouper` `itertools` recipe](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools-recipes), though using `zip` since we know it's paired up.